# Use drive letters on batch files

Tags: batch-file

I use a script to scan the entire user's drive C for specific files, and then log the results in a txt on the network. It works like a charm.

This is the script:

```
@echo off

pushd C:\
dir /s /a-d "setup.txt" /s "setup2.txt" >nul && (goto printresult) || (goto notfound)

:printresult
dir /s /a-d setup.txt /s setup2.txt >>"\\servidor\pastadelogs\FOUND_%computername%.txt
popd
exit

:notfound
echo "Este PC não possui os arquivos" >>"\\servidor\pastadelogs\NOTFOUND_%computername%.txt
popd
exit
```

Now I need to improve it, making it scan inside usb drives as well. I already have a code that will give me the usb letters:

```
  @echo off
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2,3,4 " %%i in (`wmic logicaldisk get caption^,description^,drivetype 2^>NUL`) do (

    if %%l equ 2 (
    echo %%i is a drive letter

        )
        )
```

My 2 questions are:

- Can I use them together?
- What if there is more than one USB plugged? How will it work? Can I set 1 variable per drive letter result?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the task is also scanning slow USB media then it's wise to create a file with the result on the first pass, and simply `type` the data to the target file if there is a result, rather than doing the scan again.

This is untested and will check removable and local disks: (excluding A: and B:)

**Edited**

This uses a method of choosing what drives etc NOT to include (in the findstr command): such as drive letters, and drive type numbers, and the `ID` removes the header.

```
@echo off
set "file=%temp%\drivescan.tmp"
for /f "tokens=1,2" %%a in ('wmic logicaldisk get deviceid^,drivetype^|findstr /i /v "a: b: 0 1 4 5 6 ID"') do (
    echo Processing drive %%a
    (dir /b /s /a-d "%%a\setup.txt" "%%a\setup2.txt")>"%file%" 2>nul
    for %%d in ("%file%") do if %%~zd NEQ 0 (
      type "%file%" >> "\\servidor\pastadelogs\FOUND_%computername%.txt"
        ) else (
      echo "[%%a] Este PC não possui os arquivos">>"\\servidor\pastadelogs\NOTFOUND_%computername%.txt"
    )
    del "%file%" 2>nul
)
```

Here is a list of the drive types I googled:

```
wmic logicaldisk where drivetype=2 get deviceid, volumename, description

Types

0 => Unknown
1 => No Root Directory
2 => Removable Disk
3 => Local Disk
4 => Network Drive
5 => Compact Disc
6 => RAM Disk
```

Comment: This works a lot better than mine, you are correct, it is way better than scanning the device twice. I still get an error when no disc is present on drive A. I'm running the test on a vmware machine. Do you think that it may be possible to exclude A and B drives by any chance? Also, results for C drive are showing up twice somehow, not that this is a big issue. Regards.

Comment: Also, if it could avoid any error popup being displayed it would be great. Thank you!

Comment: @LuizGustavoBatista  The code should now exclude a: and b: and make sure to delete the target file before running your test. Drive c: should only be scanned once as I understand it.

Comment: You are the best! Works like a charm!! Just saved my life!

Comment: One last observation, if it does not find any of the files (setup.txt, setup2.txt), it is atill generating a blank FOUND txt file instead of a NOTFOUND txt file.

Comment: @LuizGustavoBatista  Thanks Luiz - I modified the code to fix that, and it's quite different.  Hopefully it's working ok.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
for /f %%i in ('wmic logicaldisk where "drivetype=2" get caption^|find ":"') do (
  pushd %%i
    dir /s /a-d "setup.txt" /s "setup2.txt" >nul && (
      dir /b /s /a-d setup.txt /s setup2.txt >>"\\servidor\pastadelogs\FOUND_%computername%.txt"
    ) || (
      echo "[%%i] Este PC não possui os arquivos" >>"\\servidor\pastadelogs\NOTFOUND_%computername%.txt"
    )
  popd
)
```

this will be processed for every usb drive

Comment: Thank you, but I got an error saying there was no disk in drive A. Is it possible to include C drive, every USB and exclude all others? (CD, DVD, etc). Since this will be done silently, I can't have any error message popping on the screen. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Also another partition that the computer might have, except network drives...thank you so much!

Comment: Running the test here again I see that it found the files inside C: but it did not scan the USB. The results came twice for the same drive like this:

C:\Users\gi-tecso\Dropbox\2-Gustavo\LUGUTA\SOFTWARES\SCRIPTS\setup.txt
C:\Users\gi-tecso\Dropbox\2-Gustavo\LUGUTA\SOFTWARES\SCRIPTS\setup.txt

Comment: This is what I get now:

Node - AX-NTB-000787
ERROR:
Description = Invalid query

Comment: Try `for /f "tokens=2" %%i in ('wmic logicaldisk where "drivetype=2"^|find ":"') do (echo %%i)`

Comment: try again - I had another typo (not my day today...)

Comment: @Hackoo for `tokens=2` you'd need `/value` and `delims==`